# Flasky on Digital Ocean (ubuntu + nginx + uWsgi)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

i am flask and python beginner and i need help with deployment of flask project.
I want create prototype of [Miguel Griberg's "Flasky"](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky) app on Digital Ocean, Ubuntu server (nginx + uwsgi).

I have clone of flasky, commit 17d but i don't uderstand how must create uwsgi and other config files.

When i try create test app step by step with this [manual on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04), everything works fine, but Miguel's works with flask.ext.script and file "manage.py" and this concept is much different like Digital Ocean manual (for beginner).

I'm grateful for every instructions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could please try this one, change `wsgi.py` to:

```
from manage import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```